# How to add a Distribution List as a member of another Distribution List on Office365 through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office365

I would like to add distribution lists containing the word "Chicken" into the distribution lists that I have specified in an array.

The code is below:

```
$Client = "Chicken"

$DistributionLists = @("Chicken Analysts", "Chicken Developers", "Chicken Testers")

$ClientGroups = Get-DistributionGroup | Where-Object {$_.Client -contains $Client}

ForEach($List in $DistributionLists)
    {
    Add-DistributionGroupMember `
    -Identity $DistributionLists `
    -Member $ClientGroups
    }
```

The problems I am encountering are:

1. The array is not being passed through the -Identity parameter. The script works when I specify the distribution list as a single parameter.
2. The script is adding my admin account into these lists so the $ClientGroups line isn't working.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Looking at the Microsoft link for `Add-DistributionGroupMember`, it doesn't appear that the `-Identity` and `-Member` parameters accepts arrays. If that is the case, you will need to iterate through both lists. Can you explain the purpose of `$_.Client`? I don't see that property for object `DistributionGroup`.

Comment: Since the values in `$DistributionLists` already contain `Chicken`, do you want them to all be members of themselves or do you want those groups excluded from the search?

Comment: @AdminOfThings Hi, the clients containing "Chicken" are already added as Distribution Lists within Office 365 so the idea was to grab them from there. I would prefer for those to be excluded.